# PyroCMs for some large applications

Tags: php, pyrocms

I would like to use PyroCMS for a golf company website. PyroCMS have very great admin panel and we can also use themes to change whole look of website.

I want to modify, extend admin in such a way the whole admin will be where I can easily manage players, contents, registrations etc.

it means I want to add extra tabs in admin panel from where control website functions.

Is this possible?

Comment: You best ask this on the PyroCMS forums. This feels too broad as a question for Stack Overflow, and isn't exactly a *programming* question either.

Comment: @Pekka, I agree that the question is not phrased well, but with respect I think you're being a little harsh... the OP needs to write custom modules in PHP using both CI and Pyro classes in order to accomplish his objective. In what way is that not a programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a perfect documentation for PyroCMS on their website. You should look into that.
When making your own modules (thus making new buttons inside the admin panel) you can always refer to existing modules.

Also the forums can help you out if you have specific coding questions.
Be aware that PyroCMS is based upon the framework "CodeIgniter", and their "User Guide" is also a good source when developing.

On a sidenote:
When online, be sure that there's always a "Powered by PyroCMS" link visible when you did not buy a license. The free license forbids to take the copyrights away.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @ken . i am looking at these all stuff.

Comment: Documentation is far from perfect, very far.
Also. XSS on PyroCMS module Streams in 2014?????? OMG